# Format notifications email in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, devops

How to format the email in jenkins? I want to send an email when the build is successful contains button that directed to the deployment job.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [email-ext](https://plugins.jenkins.io/email-ext/) plugin and check for documentation with [sending-notification-pipeline](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/sending-notifications-pipeline).

You can use it like this, using environment variables :

```
emailext (
    subject: "${env.JOB_NAME}#[${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]",
    body: """<h1>Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]':</h1>
        <p>Check console output at <a href='${env.BUILD_URL}'>${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]</a></p>""",
    recipientProviders: [[$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider']]
)
```

You can use html in the body and format the message as you want.